# How to not request users to enter their old passwords when ticking "User must change password at next logon" in active directory?

Tags: active-directory, migration

My problem is that I'm doing a migration from Linux mailserver "Postfix" to Exchange using a Microsoft tool called "Microsoft transporter suite" this tool requires that all users to have their passwords entered in "CSV" file in order to access their mailboxes through IMAP protocol and migrate them to Exchange.

Talking to the Customer i'm doing the migration for, he said users can't share their passwords and we can't reset their passwords too because we'll have to send them all the same password to their e-mails before resetting it since Postfix authenticate to AD.

I'm trying to find away to reset their passwords in order to do the migration but when they are prompted reset their passwords on their PCs they don't have to type the old password!

Is this ever possible on AD? If not is there script that would generate passwords on AD and send it to the user's mail before resetting it?

I have 850 users and there's no way I can tell each one to personally come and enter their password...

Im out of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix is not an IMAP server, so what are you actually using as an IMAP server currently?

I don't know this "Transport suite" tool or Exchange at all, but if it only needs the password for the old IMAP server and *not* the Exchange password, what might work is to configure the old IMAP server to use another auth source instead of AD and create fake users in it with a password you know.

Comment: On Linux there's dovecot, and I already suggested changing authentication method but customer refused to due to security restriction. 

I was having a conversation with the IT manager and he suggested resetting the password based on each user's ID card number which everyone has. but is there any script that works on AD that would pull username and password from a text file ?

What would solve the problem probably since we can send an e-mail to all users before resetting their passwords and tell them there passwords will become their ID card number upon reset request on their PCs.

Comment: This will be a support nightmare. First, it's a lot more insecure than my approach as it's quite likely the ID number is not a closely guarded secret and might be easy to just guess. Second, expect anywhere from 20 to 80 percent of the users to not read and/or understand the instructions about the password change. Writing a script for this password change will likely be the easy part with a bit of AD knowledge.

Comment: It's not going to be the ID only as far as they told me. they are adding something else but to be honest i'm not sure what it is. since i'm in a foreign country "Turkey" and they seem it's going to be a secure method.

Yes you're right, I've got the script for this change! 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/38fa25bf-007c-45a9-8065-5b53a5868d5c/multiple-password-resets-with-powershell

Comment: I think i can close this question now, although I couldn't use your method but in any other environment where there's no lot of security restriction I would choose your method instead of mine. therefore i'm approving ur answer.
Thanks for ur time.